# How do you make an element "flash" in jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, element, highlight, flashing

I'm brand new to jQuery and have some experience using Prototype. In Prototype, there is a method to "flash" an element — ie. briefly highlight it in another color and have it fade back to normal so that the user's eye is drawn to it. Is there such a method in jQuery? I see fadeIn, fadeOut, and animate, but I don't see anything like "flash". Perhaps one of these three can be used with appropriate inputs?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP, but the (loosely tested) code may be useful to future google searchers (such as myself): `$.fn.flash = function(times, duration) {
 var T = this;

 times = times || 3;
 duration = duration || 200;

    for ( var i=0; i < times; i++ )
    {
     (function() {

      setTimeout(function() {
       T.fadeOut(duration, function() {
        T.fadeIn(duration);
       });
      }, i*duration*2+50);

     })(i);
    }
};`

Comment: add this css to the element : `text-decoration:blink`, then remove it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=blink+html

Comment: I put a JSFiddle demo here that I think is a better answer than I found on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52283660/470749

Comment: Please note that **_blink_** is officially deprecated in favor of animations. 
 
Check at: [w3.org/TR/2019/CR-css-text-decor-3-20190813/#valdef-text-decoration-line-blink](https://www.w3.org/TR/2019/CR-css-text-decor-3-20190813/#valdef-text-decoration-line-blink)

Answer (score 392):

My way is .fadein, .fadeout .fadein, .fadeout ......

```
$("#someElement").fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
```

```js
function go1() { $("#demo1").fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100)}

function go2() { $('#demo2').delay(100).fadeOut().fadeIn('slow') }
```

```css
#demo1,
#demo2 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: IndianRed;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="go1()">Click Me</button>
<div id='demo1'>My Element</div>
<br>
<button onclick="go2()">Click Me</button> (from comment)
<div id='demo2'>My Element</div>
```

Comment: Not the most beautiful solution, but short, easy to understand, and doesn't require UI/effects.  Nice!

Comment: i use a delay before the fadeIn, fadeOut sequence, something like      `$('..').delay(100).fadeOut().fadeIn('slow')`

Comment: flashing backgrounds often look tacky, or just plain jarring - especially if the item you're flashing is sitting on a plain white background. try this first before adding color plugins and trying to flash backgrounds etc.

Comment: The problem with this method is these events are potentially stepping on each other. You should probably put each subsequent fadeIn and fadeOut in their respective callbacks. For example:

    `var $someElement = $("#someElement");
    $someElement.fadeIn(100, function(){ $someElement.fadeOut(100, function(){ /*...etc...*/ }) })`

Comment: Beware using this in validation code that might be called frequently. If the code is called with the right timing you might wind up with an element showing when it shouldn't (or vice versa)

Answer (score 126):

You can use the [jQuery Color plugin](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color).

For example, to draw attention to all the divs on your page, you could use the following code:

```
$("div").stop().css("background-color", "#FFFF9C")
    .animate({ backgroundColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 1500);
```

**Edit - New and improved**

The following uses the same technique as above, but it has the added benefits of:

- parameterized highlight color and duration
- retaining original background color, instead of assuming that it is white
- being an extension of jQuery, so you can use it on any object

Extend the jQuery Object:

```
var notLocked = true;
$.fn.animateHighlight = function(highlightColor, duration) {
    var highlightBg = highlightColor || "#FFFF9C";
    var animateMs = duration || 1500;
    var originalBg = this.css("backgroundColor");
    if (notLocked) {
        notLocked = false;
        this.stop().css("background-color", highlightBg)
            .animate({backgroundColor: originalBg}, animateMs);
        setTimeout( function() { notLocked = true; }, animateMs);
    }
};
```

Usage example:

```
$("div").animateHighlight("#dd0000", 1000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there is a bug in jQuery that intermittently prevents the color from changing -> http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4251

Comment: this is quite versatile (you can animate any property, like color, instead of backgroundColor). In fact there is a bug, but if this effect is for eye-candy only, it is sufficient to wrap the call with a try-catch block: if it fails, it won't show, but it won't produce errors either.

Comment: If anyone is wondering... this was does work now! (tested in FF, Safari, Chrome)

Comment: Doesn't work for me either - are you sure this isn't relying on the color animations plugin? http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

Comment: From jquery docs on .animate() : *All animated properties should be a single numeric value (except as noted below); properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality. (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be.)* So I guess you are utilising a plugin without realising it.

Comment: @UpTheCreek good catch. My project also depends on jQuery UI, which adds the ability to animate color (http://jqueryui.com/docs/Effects/Methods#Color_Transitions). However, as another user points out below, jQuery provides an effect called 'highlight' now, which provides the same functionality

Comment: @colbeerhey: Unfortunately that highlight effect is part of JQueryUI (core effects), you can't use it with just jquery.

Comment: I noticed it didnt return an object. I tried stacking this little effect (EG: $("#qtyonhand").animateHighlight("#c3d69b", 1500).delay(1500).animateHighlight("#76923C", 5000); )  and got an error. I needed to add "return this;" to the end of the method.

Comment: I learned a lot about creating jquery functions thanks to your post. Thanks!

Comment: It does work. Requires jQuery UI. Also note that on browsers that support semi-transparent background colors (rgba), jQuery UI stable release does not support and will not animate correctly. Also, using `addClass('class', 1000)` will animate the element to that class.

Comment: Rubbish. Does not Work with latest jQuery UI.

Comment: Worked for me with jquery-1.7.2 and jquery-ui-1.8.22.

Comment: You're all a bunch of haters. This works fine, make sure you don't put your function declaration inside your document.ready function. This does NOT have a dependency on jquery-ui: both the .animate() and the .stop() methods are native to jquery.

Comment: Official jQuery Docs say you must use the jQuery.Color() plugin for this to work: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color

Comment: From the jquery .animate docs: `Note: The jQuery UI project extends the .animate() method by allowing some non-numeric styles such as colors to be animated.` - If you want to animate colour, you NEED jQuery UI or some other plugin.

Comment: What the hell, wrong information on SO with +77/-15 ? What is this? Nobody cared to edit this answer? I'm doing that right now...

Comment: I tried this with a <select> element... changed color but did not change it back.

Comment: urm... hows about somebody that can get this working makes a jsfiddle for it?

Comment: If anyone is having issues with this, please comment on what your issue is. We cannot help you if you don't give us something to work with!

Comment: Eeck! This worked in StackOverflow.com console, but not my site, nor JSFiddle! Now my vote is locked in and I can't downvote! http://jsfiddle.net/Xp4k2/

Comment: The code above does work, you just need to include jQuery Color plugin as the post says.

Answer (score 109):

You can use css3 animations to flash an element

```
.flash {
  -moz-animation: flash 1s ease-out;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -webkit-animation: flash 1s ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;

  -ms-animation: flash 1s ease-out;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes flash {
    0% { background-color: transparent; }
    50% { background-color: #fbf8b2; }
    100% { background-color: transparent; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes flash {
    0% { background-color: transparent; }
    50% { background-color: #fbf8b2; }
    100% { background-color: transparent; }
}

@-moz-keyframes flash {
    0% { background-color: transparent; }
    50% { background-color: #fbf8b2; }
    100% { background-color: transparent; }
}

@-ms-keyframes flash {
    0% { background-color: transparent; }
    50% { background-color: #fbf8b2; }
    100% { background-color: transparent; }
}
```

And you jQuery to add the class

```
jQuery(selector).addClass("flash");
```

Comment: Nice solution, if it needs to work only once. After the class has been added, subsequently adding the class does (logically) not result in flashing the element.

Comment: The best idea ever. I used a settimeout to remove the class 2 seconds after the effect

Comment: Here's an example of removing the class after the animation's done so you can keep flashing it. http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/eTcXX/1/

Comment: Great, that works, but note that the correct property for the background-color is 'transparent' instead of 'none' if you want to pass a style sheet validator.

Comment: Chrome seemingly doesn't respond to the `-webkit` prefix anymore so a `@keyframes` at-rule is needed.

Comment: Note that all modern browsers now support the regular `@keyframes` and `animation` rules, so there's no need to use any prefixed versions besides *maybe* `-webkit-` (for the Blackberry browser).

Comment: I love CSS solutions, but it's a lot of code to flash something, compared to javascript. Especially since you're using jQuery anyway.

Comment: Obvious note, but useful to mention: This will appear as if it's not working if children elements already have a background!

Comment: Modify your answer adding a delay to remove the class to allow more calls `jQuery(selector).addClass("flash").delay(1000).queue(function(){ $(this).removeClass("flash").dequeue() });`

Answer (score 85):

#### After 5 years... (And no additional plugin needed)

This one "pulses" it to the color you want (e.g. white) by **putting a div background** color behind it, and then **fading the object** out and in again.

**HTML** object (e.g. button):

```
<div style="background: #fff;">
  <input type="submit" class="element" value="Whatever" />
</div>
```

**jQuery** (vanilla, no other plugins):

```
$('.element').fadeTo(100, 0.3, function() { $(this).fadeTo(500, 1.0); });
```

**element** - class name

**first number** in `fadeTo()` - milliseconds for the transition

**second number** in `fadeTo()` - opacity of the object after fade/unfade

You may check this out in the lower right corner of this webpage: https://single.majlovesreg.one/v1/

**Edit** (willsteel) no duplicated selector by using $(this) and tweaked values to acutally perform a flash (as the OP requested).

Comment: `fadeTo(0000)` - Metallica

Comment: Smooth as butter! Best solution of all. Thanks!

Comment: how to do this infinite?

Comment: Example link broken.

Comment: Excellent and easy jQuery solution.

Comment: For some reason, fadeIn and fadeOut didn't work. But fadeTo did for me! Cheers!

Comment: @tomexsans `$.fn.flashUnlimited=function(){$(this).fadeTo('medium',0.3,function(){$(this).fadeTo('medium',1.0,$(this).flashUnlimited);});}` You can then call it like `$('#mydiv').flashUnlimited();` - It does what Majal answered above, and calls itself again at the end of the cycle.

Answer (score 47):

You could use the [highlight effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) in jQuery UI to achieve the same, I guess.

Comment: That's part of jQueryUI, which is pretty heavy, not part of the standard jQuery Library (although you could just use the UI effects core, which it relies on).

Comment: You can download just the effects core + the effect you want, which, for "highlight" + "pulsate" amounts to 12 KB. Not totally light, but not that heavy either.

Answer (score 46):

If you're using jQueryUI, there is `pulsate` function in `UI/Effects`

```
$("div").click(function () {
      $(this).effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000);
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Pulsate

Comment: @DavidYell, open a new question and post some sample code.  `pulsate` works fine in Chrome.

Comment: Blink at every 5 seconds: setInterval(function() { $(".red-flag").effect("pulsate", { times:3 }, 2000); }, 5000);

Comment: @all Does anyone now if this uses css3 animations and/or transform? Nice anyways (but still I prefer css3 as in one of the other answers)

Answer (score 18):

```
$('#district').css({opacity: 0});
$('#district').animate({opacity: 1}, 700 );
```

Comment: This is just simple and elegant.

Comment: While using `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` affects other sibling elements because it toggles css `display` property, look weird in my case. But this one fix the issue. Thanks, it works elegantly like a charm.

Answer (score 16):

#### Pure jQuery solution.

(no jquery-ui/animate/color needed.)

If all you want is that yellow "flash" effect without loading jquery color:

```
var flash = function(elements) {
  var opacity = 100;
  var color = "255, 255, 20" // has to be in this format since we use rgba
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    opacity -= 3;
    if (opacity <= 0) clearInterval(interval);
    $(elements).css({background: "rgba("+color+", "+opacity/100+")"});
  }, 30)
};
```

Above script simply does 1s yellow fadeout, perfect for letting the user know the element was was updated or something similar.

Usage:

```
flash($('#your-element'))
```

Comment: Love this solution, except the background doesn't go back to what it used to be

Answer (score 14):

You could use this plugin (put it in a js file and use it via script-tag)

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color

And then use something like this:

```
jQuery.fn.flash = function( color, duration )
{

    var current = this.css( 'color' );

    this.animate( { color: 'rgb(' + color + ')' }, duration / 2 );
    this.animate( { color: current }, duration / 2 );

}
```

This adds a 'flash' method to all jQuery objects:

```
$( '#importantElement' ).flash( '255,0,0', 1000 );
```

Answer (score 11):

You can extend Desheng Li's method further by allowing an iterations count to do multiple flashes like so:

```
// Extend jquery with flashing for elements
$.fn.flash = function(duration, iterations) {
    duration = duration || 1000; // Default to 1 second
    iterations = iterations || 1; // Default to 1 iteration
    var iterationDuration = Math.floor(duration / iterations);

    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        this.fadeOut(iterationDuration).fadeIn(iterationDuration);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Then you can call the method with a time and number of flashes:

```
$("#someElementId").flash(1000, 4); // Flash 4 times over a period of 1 second
```

Comment: Changed to `var iterationDuration = Math.floor(duration / iterations);` so that you could divide by odd numbers and made it `return this;` so that you could chain other methods after it.

Comment: This doesnt really change the color of anything though?

Answer (score 8):

How about a really simple answer?

`$('selector').fadeTo('fast',0).fadeTo('fast',1).fadeTo('fast',0).fadeTo('fast',1)`

Blinks twice...that's all folks!

Comment: That doesn't blink in another color (which was requested) this simply fades opacity in and out.

Answer (score 7):

I can't believe this isn't on this question yet. All you gotta do:

```
("#someElement").show('highlight',{color: '#C8FB5E'},'fast');
```

This does exactly what you want it to do, is super easy, works for both `show()` and `hide()` methods.

Comment: Note: for this to work, you need jquery ui's effects added. it's not part of core jQuery

Answer (score 7):

This may be a more up-to-date answer, and is shorter, as things have been consolidated somewhat since this post.  Requires **jquery-ui-effect-highlight**.

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

Answer (score 7):

```
function pulse() {
    $('.blink').fadeIn(300).fadeOut(500);
}
setInterval(pulse, 1000);
```

Comment: Exactly.  Simple, and complete control over fade in and fade out.

Answer (score 6):

I was looking for a solution to this problem but without relying on jQuery UI.

This is what I came up with and it works for me (no plugins, just Javascript and jQuery);
-- Heres the working fiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/CriddleCraddle/yYcaY/2/

Set the current CSS parameter in your CSS file as normal css, and create a new class that just handles the parameter to change i.e. background-color, and set it to '!important' to override the default behavior. like this...

```
.button_flash {
background-color: #8DABFF !important;
}//This is the color to change to.
```

Then just use the function below and pass in the DOM element as a string, an integer for the number of times you would want the flash to occur, the class you want to change to, and an integer for delay.

Note: If you pass in an even number for the 'times' variable, you will end up with the class you started with, and if you pass an odd number you will end up with the toggled class. Both are useful for different things.  I use the 'i' to change the delay time, or they would all fire at the same time and the effect would be lost.

```
function flashIt(element, times, klass, delay){
  for (var i=0; i < times; i++){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $(element).toggleClass(klass);
    }, delay + (300 * i));
  };
};

//Then run the following code with either another delay to delay the original start, or
// without another delay.  I have provided both options below.

//without a start delay just call
flashIt('.info_status button', 10, 'button_flash', 500)

//with a start delay just call
setTimeout(function(){
  flashIt('.info_status button', 10, 'button_flash', 500)
}, 4700);
// Just change the 4700 above to your liking for the start delay.  In this case, 
//I need about five seconds before the flash started.
```

Answer (score 5):

Would a <del>[pulse effect](http://enhance.qd-creative.co.uk/demos/pulse/)</del>(offline) JQuery plugin be appropriate for what you are looking for ?

You can add a duration for limiting the pulse effect in time.

---

As mentioned by **[J-P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21677/j-p)** in the comments, there is now *his* [updated pulse plugin](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/simple-pulse-plugin-for-jquery/).
See his [GitHub repo](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/pulse). And here is [a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9sWRT/207/).

Comment: Updated pulse plugin: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/simple-pulse-plugin-for-jquery/

Comment: The demo is broken, because the js library it refers to doesn't exist

Comment: @PandaWood I have restored the link to the GitHub repo and updated the demo

Answer (score 5):

Found this many moons later but if anyone cares, it seems like this is a nice way to get something to flash permanently:

```
$( "#someDiv" ).hide();

setInterval(function(){
     $( "#someDiv" ).fadeIn(1000).fadeOut(1000);
},0)
```

Answer (score 4):

The following codes work for me. Define two fade-in and fade-out functions and put them in each other's callback.

```
var fIn = function() { $(this).fadeIn(300, fOut); };
var fOut = function() { $(this).fadeOut(300, fIn); };
$('#element').fadeOut(300, fIn);
```

The following controls the times of flashes:

```
var count = 3;
var fIn = function() { $(this).fadeIn(300, fOut); };
var fOut = function() { if (--count > 0) $(this).fadeOut(300, fIn); };
$('#element').fadeOut(300, fIn);
```

Answer (score 3):

If including a library is overkill here is a solution that is guaranteed to work.

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color','#FFFFCC');
    setTimeout(function() { $(this).fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow'); } , 1000); 
    setTimeout(function() { $(this).css('background-color','#FFFFFF'); } , 1000); 
});
```

1. Setup event trigger
2. Set the background color of block element
3. Inside setTimeout use fadeOut and fadeIn to create a little animation effect.
4. Inside second setTimeout reset default background color

   Tested in a few browsers and it works nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Like fadein / fadeout you could use animate css / delay

```
$(this).stop(true, true).animate({opacity: 0.1}, 100).delay(100).animate({opacity: 1}, 100).animate({opacity: 0.1}, 100).delay(100).animate({opacity: 1}, 100);
```

Simple and flexible

Answer (score 3):

```
$("#someElement").fadeTo(3000, 0.3 ).fadeTo(3000, 1).fadeTo(3000, 0.3 ).fadeTo(3000, 1);
```

3000 is 3 seconds

From opacity 1 it is faded to 0.3, then to 1 and so on.

You can stack more of these.

Only jQuery is needed. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is a workaround for the animate background bug.  This gist includes an example of a simple highlight method and its use.

```
/* BEGIN jquery color */
  (function(jQuery){jQuery.each(['backgroundColor','borderBottomColor','borderLeftColor','borderRightColor','borderTopColor','color','outlineColor'],function(i,attr){jQuery.fx.step[attr]=function(fx){if(!fx.colorInit){fx.start=getColor(fx.elem,attr);fx.end=getRGB(fx.end);fx.colorInit=true;}
  fx.elem.style[attr]="rgb("+[Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos*(fx.end[0]-fx.start[0]))+fx.start[0]),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos*(fx.end[1]-fx.start[1]))+fx.start[1]),255),0),Math.max(Math.min(parseInt((fx.pos*(fx.end[2]-fx.start[2]))+fx.start[2]),255),0)].join(",")+")";}});function getRGB(color){var result;if(color&&color.constructor==Array&&color.length==3)
  return color;if(result=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(color))
  return[parseInt(result[1]),parseInt(result[2]),parseInt(result[3])];if(result=/rgb\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*\)/.exec(color))
  return[parseFloat(result[1])*2.55,parseFloat(result[2])*2.55,parseFloat(result[3])*2.55];if(result=/#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(color))
  return[parseInt(result[1],16),parseInt(result[2],16),parseInt(result[3],16)];if(result=/#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(color))
  return[parseInt(result[1]+result[1],16),parseInt(result[2]+result[2],16),parseInt(result[3]+result[3],16)];if(result=/rgba\(0, 0, 0, 0\)/.exec(color))
  return colors['transparent'];return colors[jQuery.trim(color).toLowerCase()];}
  function getColor(elem,attr){var color;do{color=jQuery.curCSS(elem,attr);if(color!=''&&color!='transparent'||jQuery.nodeName(elem,"body"))
  break;attr="backgroundColor";}while(elem=elem.parentNode);return getRGB(color);};var colors={aqua:[0,255,255],azure:[240,255,255],beige:[245,245,220],black:[0,0,0],blue:[0,0,255],brown:[165,42,42],cyan:[0,255,255],darkblue:[0,0,139],darkcyan:[0,139,139],darkgrey:[169,169,169],darkgreen:[0,100,0],darkkhaki:[189,183,107],darkmagenta:[139,0,139],darkolivegreen:[85,107,47],darkorange:[255,140,0],darkorchid:[153,50,204],darkred:[139,0,0],darksalmon:[233,150,122],darkviolet:[148,0,211],fuchsia:[255,0,255],gold:[255,215,0],green:[0,128,0],indigo:[75,0,130],khaki:[240,230,140],lightblue:[173,216,230],lightcyan:[224,255,255],lightgreen:[144,238,144],lightgrey:[211,211,211],lightpink:[255,182,193],lightyellow:[255,255,224],lime:[0,255,0],magenta:[255,0,255],maroon:[128,0,0],navy:[0,0,128],olive:[128,128,0],orange:[255,165,0],pink:[255,192,203],purple:[128,0,128],violet:[128,0,128],red:[255,0,0],silver:[192,192,192],white:[255,255,255],yellow:[255,255,0],transparent:[255,255,255]};})(jQuery);
  /* END jquery color */


  /* BEGIN highlight */
  jQuery(function() {
    $.fn.highlight = function(options) {
      options = (options) ? options : {start_color:"#ff0",end_color:"#fff",delay:1500};
      $(this).each(function() {
        $(this).stop().css({"background-color":options.start_color}).animate({"background-color":options.end_color},options.delay);
      });
    }
  });
  /* END highlight */

  /* BEGIN highlight example */
  $(".some-elements").highlight();
  /* END highlight example */
```

https://gist.github.com/1068231

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the top answer requires JQuery UI. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

## Here is a vanilla JQuery solution

http://jsfiddle.net/EfKBg/

#### JS

```
var flash = "<div class='flash'></div>";
$(".hello").prepend(flash);
$('.flash').show().fadeOut('slow');
```

#### CSS

```
.flash {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="hello">Hello World!</div>
```

Comment: If you just make `flash` a jQuery Object, it works fine.
`var flash = $("<div class='flash'></div>");
$(".hello").prepend(flash);
flash.show().fadeOut('slow');`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly improved version of colbeerhey's solution.  I added a return statement so that, in true jQuery form, we chain events after calling the animation. I've also added the arguments to clear the queue and jump to the end of an animation.

```
// Adds a highlight effect
$.fn.animateHighlight = function(highlightColor, duration) {
    var highlightBg = highlightColor || "#FFFF9C";
    var animateMs = duration || 1500;
    this.stop(true,true);
    var originalBg = this.css("backgroundColor");
    return this.css("background-color", highlightBg).animate({backgroundColor: originalBg}, animateMs);
};
```

Comment: note: animating background colors requires the use of the colors UI plugin. see: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

This one will pulsate an element's background color until a mouseover event is triggered

```
$.fn.pulseNotify = function(color, duration) {

var This = $(this);
console.log(This);

var pulseColor = color || "#337";
var pulseTime = duration || 3000;
var origBg = This.css("background-color");
var stop = false;

This.bind('mouseover.flashPulse', function() {
    stop = true;
    This.stop();
    This.unbind('mouseover.flashPulse');
    This.css('background-color', origBg);
})

function loop() {
    console.log(This);
    if( !stop ) {
        This.animate({backgroundColor: pulseColor}, pulseTime/3, function(){
            This.animate({backgroundColor: origBg}, (pulseTime/3)*2, 'easeInCirc', loop);
        });
    }
}

loop();

return This;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put this together from all of the above - an easy solution for flashing an element and return to the original bgcolour...

```
$.fn.flash = function (highlightColor, duration, iterations) {
    var highlightBg = highlightColor || "#FFFF9C";
    var animateMs = duration || 1500;
    var originalBg = this.css('backgroundColor');
    var flashString = 'this';
    for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++) {
        flashString = flashString + '.animate({ backgroundColor: highlightBg }, animateMs).animate({ backgroundColor: originalBg }, animateMs)';
    }
    eval(flashString);
}
```

Use like this:

```
$('<some element>').flash('#ffffc0', 1000, 3);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beware of the evil ```eval```!

Comment: I know, I just needed a quick and dirty solution. Eval has it's uses sometimes!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that uses a mix of jQuery and CSS3 animations.

http://jsfiddle.net/padfv0u9/2/

Essentially you start by changing the color to your "flash" color, and then use a CSS3 animation to let the color fade out.  You need to change the transition duration in order for the initial "flash" to be faster than the fade.

```
$(element).removeClass("transition-duration-medium");
$(element).addClass("transition-duration-instant");
$(element).addClass("ko-flash");
setTimeout(function () {
    $(element).removeClass("transition-duration-instant");
    $(element).addClass("transition-duration-medium");
    $(element).removeClass("ko-flash");
}, 500);
```

Where the CSS classes are as follows.

```
.ko-flash {
    background-color: yellow;
}
.transition-duration-instant {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
.transition-duration-medium {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 1s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 1s;
    -o-transition-duration: 1s;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

just give elem.fadeOut(10).fadeIn(10);

Answer (score 1):

This is generic enough that you can write whatever code you like to animate. You can even decrease the delay from 300ms to 33ms and fade colors, etc.

```
// Flash linked to hash.
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
if (hash) {
    hash = $("#" + hash);
    var color = hash.css("color"), count = 1;
    function hashFade () {
        if (++count < 7) setTimeout(hashFade, 300);
        hash.css("color", count % 2 ? color : "red");
    }
    hashFade();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery Pulsate plugin to force to focus the attention on any html element with control over speed and repeatation and color.

[JQuery.pulsate()](https://kilianvalkhof.com/jquerypulsate) <sup>** with Demos*</sup>

sample initializer:

- $(".pulse4").pulsate({speed:2500})
- $(".CommandBox button:visible").pulsate({ color: "#f00", speed: 200, reach: 85, repeat: 15 })

Answer (score 0):

I am using this one. though not yet tested on all browser. 
just modify this in the way you like,

usage: `hlight($("#mydiv"));`

```
function hlight(elementid){
    var hlight= "#fe1414"; //set the hightlight color
    var aspeed= 2000; //set animation speed
    var orig= "#ffffff"; // set default background color
    elementid.stop().css("background-color", hlight).animate({backgroundColor: orig}, aspeed);
}
```

NOTE: you need a jquery UI added to your header.

Answer (score 0):

This function makes it blink.
It must use cssHooks, because of the rgb default return of **background-color** function.

Hope it helps!

```
$.cssHooks.backgroundColor = {
get: function(elem) {
    if (elem.currentStyle)
        var bg = elem.currentStyle["backgroundColor"];
    else if (window.getComputedStyle)
        var bg = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem,
            null).getPropertyValue("background-color");
    if (bg.search("rgb") == -1)
        return bg;
    else {
        bg = bg.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        function hex(x) {
            return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }
        return "#" + hex(bg[1]) + hex(bg[2]) + hex(bg[3]);
    }
}
}
function blink(element,blinkTimes,color,originalColor){
    var changeToColor;
    if(blinkTimes === null || blinkTimes === undefined)
        blinkTimes = 1;
    if(!originalColor || originalColor === null || originalColor === undefined)
        originalColor = $(element).css("backgroundColor");
    if(!color || color === null || color === undefined)
        color = "#ffffdf";
    if($(element).css("backgroundColor") == color){
        changeToColor = originalColor;
    }else{
        changeToColor = color;
        --blinkTimes;
    }
    if(blinkTimes >= 0){
        $(element).animate({
            "background-color": changeToColor,
        }, {
            duration: 500,
            complete: function() {
                blink(element, blinkTimes, color, originalColor);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }else{
        $(element).removeAttr("style");
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple as the best is to do in this way :

```
<script>

setInterval(function(){

    $(".flash-it").toggleClass("hide");

},700)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working with jQuery 1.10.2, this pulses a dropdown twice and changes the text to an error. It also stores the values for the changed attributes to reinstate them.

```
// shows the user an error has occurred
$("#myDropdown").fadeOut(700, function(){
    var text = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var background = $(this).css( "background" );

    $(this).css('background', 'red');
    $(this).find("option:selected").text("Error Occurred");

        $(this).fadeIn(700, function(){
            $(this).fadeOut(700, function(){
                $(this).fadeIn(700, function(){
                    $(this).fadeOut(700, function(){

                        $(this).find("option:selected").text(text);
                        $(this).css("background", background);
                        $(this).fadeIn(700);
                    })
                })
            })
        })
});
```

Done via callbacks - to ensure no animations are missed.

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes, giving each a background color:

```
.flash{
 background: yellow;
}

.noflash{
 background: white;
}
```

Create a div with one of these classes:

```
<div class="noflash"></div>
```

The following function will toggle the classes and make it appear to be flashing:

```
var i = 0, howManyTimes = 7;
function flashingDiv() {
    $('.flash').toggleClass("noFlash")
    i++;
    if( i <= howManyTimes ){
        setTimeout( f, 200 );
    }
}
f();
```

Answer (score 0):

Straight jquery, no plugins. It blinks the specified number of times, changes the background color while blinking and then changes it back.

```
function blink(target, count, blinkspeed, bc) {
    let promises=[];
    const b=target.css(`background-color`);
    target.css(`background-color`, bc||b);
    for (i=1; i<count; i++) {
            const blink = target.fadeTo(blinkspeed||100, .3).fadeTo(blinkspeed||100, 1.0);
            promises.push(blink);
    }
    // wait for all the blinking to finish before changing the background color back
    $.when.apply(null, promises).done(function() {
            target.css(`background-color`, b);
    });
    promises=undefined;
}
```

Example:

```
blink($(`.alert-danger`), 5, 200, `yellow`);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code :)
change mili value for change animation speed

```
var mili = 300
for (var i = 2; i < 8; i++) {
   if (i % 2 == 0) {
      $("#lblTransferCount").fadeOut(mili)
   } else {
      $("#lblTransferCount").fadeIn(mili)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS supports flashing in all major browsers

```
.flash {
    animation: flash 0.5s ease-out;
    animation-iteration-count: 10;
}
@keyframes flash {
    0% { opacity: 0.5; }
    50% { opacity: 1.0; }
    100% { opacity: 0.5; }
}
```

add this class to the element you want to flash

```
$(elem).addClass("flash");
```

iteration-count: 10  is how many times you want it to flash, no need to remove the class, it will stop flashing on its own.

by using opacity: this works for elements of any colour as long as its not already transparent.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this cool library to make any kind of animated effect on your element: http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/