# How to change temporarily the background color of a new element added to the DOM?

Tags: jquery, dom, colors, background

I'm developing a webpage (using jquery) where the user can add new graphical controls to the DOM (for example, the user clicks on a link and a new DIV is created). How can I change the background color of this new element for a few seconds (and then it will revert back to its original color)? I want to change the color to give a visual indicator to the user about the location of the new element.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of libraries that will do this (and many other impressive graphical effects) for you, like [**jQuery**](http://jquery.com/), [**MooTools**](http://mootools.net/), and [**Prototype**](http://www.prototypejs.org/). Check out [**this StackOverflow question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275931/how-do-you-make-an-element-flash-in-jquery) for how to use jQuery to pull this effect off, for example.

More generally, you'd use Javascript's `setTimeout` method to set an element's color to something for a while, then when the timeout runs, set it back to its proper/original color.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the simplest solution to do this without using a plugin is by using the ['Highlight' feature](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) of jquery UI.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using jQuery.animate(). It doesn't use colors, but opacity:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
div {
 width: 300px;
 height: 300px;
 border: solid #000 1px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("div").click(function() {
        $("<span>Hello there!</span>").appendTo(this)
               .animate({
                    opacity: 0
               }, 500, function() {
                    $(this).animate({
                        opacity: 1,
                    }, 500);
               });
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```