# highlight div for few seconds

Tags: jquery

I have many div's, when ever I any of the div, its content gets copied to the top most div, but I want to highlight the top most div, how can I do it using jQuery.

Code:

```
<div id="code"> </div>

<div id="1">Click Me</div>
<div id="2">Click Me, please</div>
```

When I click div either with id 1 or 2, it contents get copied to div with "code" id, but I need to highlight for few seconds, so that I can notify user that something is changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you make an element "flash" in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275931/how-do-you-make-an-element-flash-in-jquery)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

try this.... jquery has [**Highlight**](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) to achieve this..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('div.success').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

Comment: I am using jQuery and jQuery UI Core, will this effect work, right now it's not working. please suggest

Comment: yes..it should work...i have given you reference for highlight..you can see there...it's working. are you getting any error?

Comment: @I-M working fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/XdUGn/ please check that and see that it works..

Comment: I include `jquery.effects.core.js` and `jquery.effects.highlight.js` from jQuery UI and it works.

Answer (score 20):

There is a simple way to achieve this using CSS and jQuery too, Check this out,

CSS

```
@keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        background: #ffff99; 
    }
    100% {
        background: none;
    }
}

.highlight {
    animation: highlight 2s;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function highlight(){
    $('#YourElement').addClass("highlight");
    setTimeout(function () {
          $('#YourElement').removeClass('highlight');
    }, 2000);
}
```

Use `highlight()` function in your events.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using jQuery UI, you can do this:

```
$('#code').effect('highlight',{},3000); // three seconds
```

Separately, your IDs on those lower two elements are invalid. You can't start an ID with a number (except, as Vivek points out, in HTML5). Instead of `1` or `2`, use something with some semantic value, like `answer1` or `article1`.

Edit: Here's how to do it using your current HTML, including a click handler for the divs:

```
$('#a1,#a2').click( function(){
   $('#code')
       .html( $.trim( $(this).text() ) )
       .effect('highlight',{},1000); 
});
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/KrhHs/

Comment: I am using jQuery and jQuery UI Core, will this effect work, right now it's not working. please suggest

Comment: Vivek, quite right, I've amended the answer. @IMJM, there was a typo in my code snippet -- a missing quote. I've fixed it; perhaps that's what's tripping you up?

Answer (score 3):

very quick and dirty way to do that (5 minutes looking on the documentation :p):

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    //when clicking on all div but not the first one
    $("div:not(:first)").click(function() {
      //Content of the selected div gets copied to the top one
      $("div:first").text($(this).text());
      //At the end of the first animation execute the second animation
      $("div:first").animate({
          opacity:"0.5"
      }, 1000, function() {
        $("div:first").animate({
            opacity:"1"
        }, 1000);
      });
    });
  });

</script>
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: As Ken and Vivek pointed out, it might be better to use `$('div:first').effect('highlight',{},3000);`

Comment: Laurent: But if you want to use .effect(), you have to include jQuery UI dependency.