# How to make an <li> element flash/blink a different color using jQuery

Tags: jquery, telerik, jquery-animate

So I am using the Telerik MVC controls for a solution that I am working on and I am specifically dealing with the Telerik **"Menu"** control item right now.

What I am trying to do is this:
If the master page loads with a certain property set to a certain value, then I will display a menu item that is very important for users to see. I want this menu item to constantly **blink** with a red/orange background in the menu bar. The telerik menu items are are rendered as `<li>`'s.

I want to write some jQuery, using **jQuery 1.6.4**, so that I can have this blinking or flashing effect on the `<li>` that is important. How can I do this? Almost all of the things that I have tried (that supposedly worked for jQuery 1.2) are not working and are throwing errors when I try them. Is there an easy way to do this using 1.6.4?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post what you've tried and what doesn't work?

Comment: From a user-experience and design perspective (rather than a pure code perspective) I would advise against blinking elements. There are other ways to get a user's attention for important information. And you'll save yourself having to write this code as well. ;-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275931/how-do-you-make-an-element-flash-in-jquery

I have tried each of the ways described there...not working for me though...the best result I have gotten was just to change the background color to the alert color...and then it just stayed that color...and threw an error in the jQuery 1.6.4 scripts

Comment: @GregPettit Maybe he's designing a Retro

Comment: @bricker Maybe. Didn't sound like it. But it's just advice to be taken under consideration or ignored as they see fit. ;-)

Comment: @GregPettit Heh, I was half-way through that joke comment when I decided it was stupid, guess I accidentally hit my `return` key before leaving the page. Whoops.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

css:

```
.blink_orange{ background-color: orange; }
.blink_red{ background-color: red; }
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
    setInterval(blinkLi, 200);    
});

function blinkLi(){
    $('ul .ClassToBlink').toggleClass('blink_orange blink_red');
};
```

Make sure to assign blink_orange or blink_red to the li when it's created.

Comment: Oh dear, it's COLOR: 22 all over again.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval) to repeat an action at a specified interval, and [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to change a CSS property:

```
var x = false;
setInterval(function() {
    $("li").css("background-color", x ? "#ff0000" : "#ffaa00");
    x = !x;
}, 500);
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/26eVE/8/) of the above. There may well be a better way of doing this (perhaps with jQuery's `animate` method with a callback), but that's what first popped into my mind.

Comment: This is very helpful and did work to make the <li> blink. Thank you!

I am hoping to find a solution that is more 'visually appealing' by having the colors fade in and out...Any advice on how to get that sort of effect? I don't mind using the jQuery UI plugin if need be for the fading effects.

Comment: Use `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` which are part of core jquery.  http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/