# A visual indication that a text field is editable

Tags: ios, user-interface, usability, user-experience

I'm developing an iPhone app. One of the screens contains several text fields, and an "edit" button. The text is static, but when the user taps the "edit" button, all the fields become editable. How do I communicate to the user via UI that they are now free to edit the text? I've played with changing the text/background color, but nothing seems right. I'll appreciate any references to apps that handle this issue nicely.

Comment: This question might be more appropriate for http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely ask it there. I did go through the list of all the StackExchange sites prior to posting the question, and somehow missed this one.

Comment: I think, just maybe, that when you have it disabled it has a grey tint, and when it becomes active it looks normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about set the textfield become first responder and show up the keyboard when user press the button.

```
[textField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it would be to change the textFieldDidBeginEditing: method to put some placeholder text in place in each of the text fields as follows:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    textField.placeholder = @"Tap to edit!";
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because there is already text in my text fields. So the placeholder text won't usually be shown.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried maybe using the placeholder option for fields?

Example:  `<input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name" />`

Ok check out this link then. It uses jQuery (not sure if your doing web or native) But the effect is making the text field "Flash", drawing attention to it.

[jQuery Flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275931/how-do-you-make-an-element-flash-in-jquery)

Comment: I'm aware of placeholders, but in my case there's already text in the text fields.