# How to refresh div in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a calculations going on in the angularjs app file, basically what is happening is every time when I change the value in the HTMl form, the calculation results are getting reflected in the span block `reloader_block`,

What I want to do is that i want to add animation to that so that the entire span block should flash and user should notice it.

Like for example, the span block should fade-out and fade-in within milliseconds.

How can I do that?

```
$scope.refreshDiv = function () {
  //here i want to refresh the span block `reloader_block`   
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<span class="block reloader_block">
  Here is how you can Walden this product: 
  You will have to share it with <B>{{sharable_with}}</b> users. Each one of you  will have to give us  <b>{{walden_costs}}</b>/- 
  Each of you will get to use the product for <b>{{usage}}</b> days after every <b>{{cycle}}</b> days
  after <b>{{product_warranty}}</b> year(s) we will auction the product at <b>30%</b> of MRP.
  {{priceful}}
</span>
```

Comment: what about invoking refreshDiv into a simple $watch?

Answer (score 1):

You would simply remove and add a class with ng-class="flashback" on the block and then in your function clear the variable and set it again with the animated background css. Find a similar css solution here ([A "flash" of color, using pure css transitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16791851/a-flash-of-color-using-pure-css-transitions))

```
$scope.refreshDiv = function () {
    $scope.flashback = "";
    $scope.flashback = "demo";
};
```

HTml:

```
<span ng-class="flashback"></div>
```

css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes demo {
    0% {
        background-color: Yellow;
        opacity:1;
    }

    100% {
        background-color: #777;
    }
}

.demo {
    -webkit-animation-name: demo;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 900ms;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css transitions and `$timeout` in conjunction:

```
.reloader_block {
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in;
}

.reloader_block-active {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

$scope.refreshDiv = function() {
    var reload_element = document.getElementsByClassName('reloader_block')[0];
    reloader_element.classList.add('reloader_block-active');
    $timeout(function() {
        reloader_element.classList.remove('reloader_block-active');
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: document.getElementsByClassNames is not valid Angular code

Comment: it is valid javascript code. Why is angular required for selecting elements?

Comment: Ok, also classList.add is not valid since you are modifying the DOM and Angular doesn't know about it, it will probably work but not the Angular way of doing things

Comment: angular doesn't HAVE to know about modyfing the DOM. It only has to know when some two way data binding is being used.

Comment: Angular is also about manupulating DOM without such code. It is valid JS but not a good practice when you have Angular in your hand.